# Why am I seeing two snippet buttons?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets, editor

I just noticed there are two snippet buttons!?

[image: 2-snippet]

Clicking either of them works as expected.

Pressing the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> opens both modal dialogs at the same time.